# Gettin to use the reg query in batch

Tags: batch-file, registry

I would like to know how I can use the reg query in batch to make if else decisions

what I have sofar is:

```
    set ANSWR = ('reg query "hklm\system\controlset001\control\nls\language" /v Installlanguage')

if %ANSWR% == "0415" (goto DUTCH) else (goto OTHER)

:DUTCH
MSG * windows is in dutch

EXIT

:OTHER

MSG * CANT FIND VERSION

EXIT
pause
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a few problems, but here is a working one

```
@ECHO off
FOR /f "tokens=3" %%a IN ('reg query^
 "HKLM\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\control\nls\language" /v InstallLanguage') DO (
    SET answer=%%a
) 
IF %answer%==0415 (
    GOTO :DUTCH
) ELSE (
    GOTO :OTHER
)

:DUTCH
MSG * windows is in dutch
GOTO :END

:OTHER
MSG * CANT FIND VERSION
GOTO :END

:END
pause
```

Comment: I'm not native to Batch, so I learn by trial and error but whats the go with tokens i did see them repetably juring my googeling and figured that they skiped or steped into menu options is this correct?

Comment: @BartvanTuÿl The token is just to say which line or lines of the command/file do you want to read. I could use `tokens=1-5` if I wanted to read the lines 1 to 5, but in this case it's just the 3rd.